# Why does multiprocess yield different timing because order of execution

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am running the following benchmark script on Windows machine. I noticed the order when multiprocess() get executed affected it's performance. If I execute multiprocess first, the execution speed is faster than simple & multithread() method, if I executed it in the end, the processing speed is almost double compared to multithread() and simple method.

```
import random
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
size = 10000000   # Number of random numbers to add to list
threads = 8 # Number of threads to create
my_list = []

for i in range(0,threads):
    my_list.append([])
def func(count, mylist):
    for i in range(count):
        mylist.append(random.random())

processes = []
for i in range(0, threads):
    p = Process(target=func,args=(size,my_list[i]))
    processes.append(p)


def multithreaded():
    jobs = []
    for i in range(0, threads):
        thread = Thread(target=func,args=(size,my_list[i]))
        jobs.append(thread)
    # Start the threads
    for j in jobs:
        j.start() 
    # Ensure all of the threads have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

def simple():
    for i in range(0, threads):
        func(size,my_list[i])

def multiprocessed():
    global processes
    # Start the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    # Ensure all processes have finished execution
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    multiprocessed()
    print("elasped time:{}".format(time.time()-start))
    start = time.time()
    simple()
    print("elasped time:{}".format(time.time()-start))
    start = time.time()
    multithreaded()
    print("elasped time:{}".format(time.time()-start))
```

- Results #1 : multiprocessed (2.85s) -> simple (7.39s) -> multithread
  (7.84s)
- Results #2 : multithread (7.84s) -> simple (7.53s) ->
  multiprocessed (13.96 s)

Why is that ? How do I properly use multiprocess function on windows in order to improve the speed by utilizing CPU cores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timing code doesn't isolate each test from the effects of the others. If you execute `multiprocessed` first, the sublists of `my_list` are empty. If you execute it last, the sublists are full of elements added by the other runs, dramatically increasing the communication overhead involved in sending the data to the worker processes.

Comment: ah, that make sense ! totally dumb question !

Comment: one question though, if my_list size is changing, why does the multithread and simple timing does not change much ?

Comment: @user2386301: Those options don't need to send the data to another process. Sending (pickles of) giant lists to worker processes is what's causing your timing discrepancy.